# Java Массив Class[]

Tags: java, массивы, классы, null

Собственно, есть класс, у которого есть поле вида

```
private static final Class[] annotatedClasses = {RoleEntity.class, UserEntity.class};
```

далее есть метод :

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
....
// код не относящийся к вопросу
for (Class c : annotatedClasses) {
     configuration.addAnnotatedClass(c);
    }
```

и получаем что массив - null
Кто то может внятно объяснить с чем связано и как обойти?
[image: debugger]

UPD:
Полный код класса

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {
   private static final Class[] annotatedClasses = {RoleEntity.class, UserEntity.class, ReturnEntity.class};
//    private static final Package pckg = Package.getPackage("com.tr1nksgroup.model.data.entities");
private static final String packageName = "com.tr1nksgroup.model.data.entities";
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(HibernateSessionFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(AppConstants.HIBERNATE_SESSION_PROPERTIES_FILEPATH));
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperties(properties);
//            configuration.addPackage(pckg.getName());
        configuration.addPackage(packageName);
        for (Class c : annotatedClasses) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(c);
        }
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: А в каком контексте выполняется вышеуказанный for, не в `static {}` ли блоке?

Comment: @etki цикл в static методе, который вызывается из static метода или при инициализации static поля.

Comment: Если эта инициализация происходит выше по коду, нежели присвоение annotatedClassed, то тут, думаю, все очевидно

Comment: @etki если вы имеете в виду порядок строк то сначала объявлен массив, потом 2 поля не относящиеся к вопросу и потом SessionFactory инициализируемый этим методом

Comment: Приведите, если не сложно, полный код

Comment: @etki Добавил полный код класса. Если что проблема решилась удалением зависимостей проекта и загрузкой их по новой.